# Vuejs v-if and page loading

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have this element in laravel blade:

```
 <span 
      v-if="notificationsCount !== 0" 
      class="pl-2 text-def font-bold" 
      v-text="notificationsCount">
</span>
```

In this condition I check if `notificationsCount > 0`, then display this `notificationsCount`.

When page loading this element loads with class `pl-2`

css:

```
.pl-2 { padding-left: 10px }
```

How can I remove this padding, when page loading and get this padding when `notificationsCount > 0` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html),

```
<span v-if="notificationsCount !== 0" v-bind:class="{ 'pl-2': notificationsCount > 0 }"></span>
```

### But

I might indicate any class  or any text has no effect when `notificationsCount` is `0` because the node is not rendered at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like:

```
<span v-if="notificationsCount !== 0" v-bind:class="{ pl-2: notificationsCount }" class="text-def font-bold" v-text="notificationsCount"></span>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Comment: @Dumitru `:class="{ 'pl-2': notificationsCount }"`

Answer (score 0):

:class="{ pl-2: notificationsCount<0 }"

Comment: Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Comment: Take a error_picture or Put your error_info on comment?

Comment: [this can definitely solve your problem](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) => read it